# Perform multiple tasks to database one at a time

Tags: swift, multithreading, sqlite, thread-safety

I´m using [Sqlite.Swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) and I want to perform three different tasks to add data to my database. Each task will get data from an external source.

So what I want to do is:

1. Get data for the first task
2. Add it to the first table
3. When this is done, go on to the next task
4. Add it to the second table
5. When this is done, go on to the last task
6. Add it to the last table

Right now I only have it like this:

```
dataService.getPlaces()
dataService.getTaxes()
dataService.getPersons()
```

But the issue is that there is over 2000 places, 100 taxes and 2000 persons so each task takes some time to complete and the database get locked when these try to run at the same time.

Anyone have any idea how to do this tasks one at a time?

Comment: What do you mean with the database gets locked?

Comment: Too much load on it because too many asynch requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSOperationQueue, there is an excellent [video online](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/) from last year's WWDC.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite, whatever the Swift library you use, does not support concurrent writes: you won't be able to write places, taxes, persons, in parallel.

This is the case even when you open multiple connections, as I guess you did because you got locking errors.

What you can do is: first load data from external sources in memory. This can be done in parallel. When all data has been loaded, you can write them to the database in a single transaction (SQLite performs much better when you group writes in a transaction).